# Excel - Convert a range of text to dates in a formula

Tags: excel, date, text, formula

The two columns in my data referred to in this formula are "Carrier" and the other column is "OriginalEffectiveDate". The second column consist of a range of dates over a two year span.   I need to show a like count of carriers for both years.

So if the range of dates is Jan 1, 2014 to July 12, 2015 then I only want to count the carriers in 2014 up to July 12, 2014.  So in other words; if I counted all of 2014 compared to just a portion of 2015 then my numbers would be off.

The results would be something like:

```
2014 = 343 (Jan 1 - July 12, 2014)
2015 = 375 (Jan 1 - July 12, 2015)
```

When I set the file up originally the data I was using was static and the dates were numeric fields.  When I took the same file and made the connection directly to the database the dates are now coming in as text and I cant get the same formula to work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
=COUNTIFS(tbl_Group[Carrier],A5,tbl_Group[OriginalEffectiveDate],"<="&EDATE(MAX(tbl_Group[OriginalEffectiveDate]),-12))
```

Photo:

[image]

Comment: Could you post a link to a photo of your data?

Comment: Have you used =VALUE("text string")  to convert a text string to its value, if it can be resolved into one? Perhaps that will help?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/602bnkv25x3v7je/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: KiwiSteve,  I have tried to use =value but cant seem to get it to work over a range of dates shown as text.

Comment: Have you tried `DATEVALUE("text string")`

Comment: Scott Craner I think I've tried everything.  Can you show me how I would use this in my formula?  Maybe I'm just not using it in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a calculated column to your table?

If so, try this: add column called `CalculatedDate` with formula `=DATEVALUE([@OriginalEffectiveDate])`

Your `CountIfS` formula becomes

```
=COUNTIFS(tbl_Group[Carrier],A10,tbl_Group[CalculatedDate],"<="&EDATE(MAX(tbl_Group[CalculatedDate]),-12))
```

Note: `DATEVALUE` will make assumptions about potentially ambiguous dates, in my case `yyyy-mm-dd` based on my regional settings.

---

The reason `COUNTIFS` can't work without a calculated column is that the `criteria_range` parameters must be a direct range, and `tbl_Group[OriginalEffectiveDate]` are strings, not dates.

An alternative formula that doesn't require a calculated column is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
  (tbl_Group[Carrier]=A12) * 
  (DATEVALUE(tbl_Group[OriginalEffectiveDate]) <=
   MAX(EDATE(DATEVALUE(tbl_Group[OriginalEffectiveDate]),-12))
  )
           )
```

Comment: yes that does work.  I was trying to avoid adding columns as I will need several.  Seemed like the DATEVALUE would work in the formula.  Thanks for letting me know that it didn't work for you as well.  I thought for sure I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I can understand wanting to avoid adding columns, but worth noting that Tables are quite good at managing calculated column when they are updated.